# JavaScript Route with message Laravel Blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I have following function which makes a redirect to my view home and pass the data to the success div.
Here you can see the return line from that message...

`return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Group is created!');`

And this is the part in my view where the message is shown...

```
@if (session('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
     {{ session('success') }}
</div>
@elseif (session('danger'))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
     {{ session('danger') }}
</div>
@endif
```

Now I have this Java Script, where I want to have the message to the same part in my view like above. I get the redirect to the correct view home, but my message is not shown.

```
    success: function(data){                
    jQuery('.alert-danger').html('<p>'+data.successsuccess+'</p>');
    window.location.href = "{{URL::to('/home')}}"
```

What I have to fix, that my message will be shown?

Thank you

Comment: You won't be able to do this frontend. The `->with` saves your message in a session. Something you could do is create a cookie in jquery and read it backend. A middleware comes to mind. Another way to do it is to post a redirect (f.ex. in a new Route called /redirect) with the message and redirect url attached.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Session::flash('message', 'This is a message!');`  and don't forget to add `use Session;` on your controller.

then you can display it like this :

```
  @if (Session::has('message'))
        <li>{!! session('message') !!}</li>
   @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead:

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
     {{ session()->get('success') }}
  </div>
@elseif (session()->has('danger'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
     {{ session()->get('danger') }}
  </div>
@endif
```